# Dependency property with my external data storage

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, dependency-properties

I want to add a property to my user control. If I understand it correctly, it must be declared as dependency property when I want to allow databinding to be used on it. Dependency property stores its value in a data field hidden somewhere in Silverlight system. But I need the data to be stored in a format other than type of the property, and here is the problem. Is it possible to declare a dependency property, but use my own data store for its value?

I am asking this for a reason. I want to allow to import and export data in xml string, but internally store them in a set of objects and be able to mobify these objects. So I want to have a `string` property, and I need to take the xml string and convert to my internal different data format, and then export it back to string when saving back to database.

The current version is a standard property. It's connected to the pair of conversion methods:

```
public string XmlData {
  get { return ExportToXML(); }
  set { ImportFromXML(value); }
}
```

How to convert this code to a dependency property (in order to allow databinding)?

**Update:**

AKAIF it is easy to implement the setter using the dependency property's callback. But there is no callback supported for the getter.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As far as I found, unfortunately, the thing I asked for, cannot be done in Silverlight.

Comment: What do you mean by "add proper answer"? The asked thing cannot be done. That's all about it.

Answer (score 1):

A dependency object has a defined type, but the main difference to simple or even update properties is that modifications of the values can occur without the getter and setting being called.

Only *Attached (dependency) properties* get their static setter called externally (during the parsing of Xaml).

The Setter/Getter pair of a DP is there for your convenience to avoid lots of casting. SetValue is actually used instead by everything else (storyboard system etc).

The upshot of this is that you can hook into the parsing with an attached property and do some of your own storage, but otherwise I think you are out of luck.

Comment: Yes I know what you write (the first three paragraphs). So it seems there is no real chance to have a dependency property as a pair of methods. I always though THIS is a real property, not just a public accessor to a private variable.

Comment: @Al Kepp: Sorry, I do not understand what you mean about "THIS" being a real property. Can you clarify?

Comment: to HiTech: In object oriented programming, a property is a syntactic sugar for a pair of related methods (get+set), not a variable which is hidden somewhere. A real property doesn't need to have a variable behind it, as I show in my question. Unfortunately, in Microsoft Silverlight properties are just special variables.

Comment: Dependency properties are not "a variable hidden somewhere". They are a named entry in a complicated dictionary attached to a DependencyObject. That allows animation to retain multiple values for the same property.... but none of this helps you.

Comment: Please pardon me for my simplification, but I really think that "a named entry in a complicated dictionary attached to a DependencyObject" is really a kind of "a variable hidden somewhere".

Comment: Please re-read my comment. They are each *not a single variable value* as you imply. The can each have multiple values at any given time and allow the animation system to work. If you oversimplify that then you ignore their benefit.